# Admin shares not accessible on Windows 7 Pro machines

Tags: active-directory, windows-7, sccm

I've been trying to deploy out the SCCM client to a lab of computers for a test bed, but for some reason I am not able to access the c$ d$ etc... shares that are required for it to install through the push method in the config manager console.

I tried allowing the File and Printer sharing firewall exception through GPO, but that has not helped.  I rebound it to the domain, still nothing.

When trying to access the share by either \HOSTNAME\c$ or \IPADDRESS\c$ I get the "Windows cannot access \HOSTNAME\c$".  Is there some other firewall rule that needs to be opened in order for them to be accessible?

I have tried from a account that is in the local admin group, as well as a Domain Admin account and get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the client push does not use the administrative shares (C$, D$, etc) to do its work.  The client *should* be pushing from `\\SERVER\SMS_<site code>`.  SCCM manages the permissions to that share automatically so you shouldn't have to mess with it.

Second, make sure that File and Printer Sharing is enabled through your firewall *for the correct profile*.  Opening those ports for private networks won't work if your location is "Domain" and vice-versa.

Third, make sure you're using two backslashes in your server name (i.e. `\\HOSTNAME`, not `\HOSTNAME`) as you have written in your question.  I don't know if that was a typo or not.

Assuming the firewall is good and the server is joined to the domain, there's no reason you shouldn't be able to connect to C$ with your domain admin account unless you're having name resolution problems on your network.

Comment: FWIW, I don't think he means the shares on the server (not pushing *from* share, \\server\sms_<site_code>), but the shares on the client (pushing *to* share, \\client\c$). The steps are the same, though; make sure on the *client* that the firewall isn't blocking File & Print on the correct profile (Domain, Private, or Guest).